# List all processes and their current memory & CPU consumption?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, cpu-usage, performancecounter

How can I get a list of all processes in C# and then for each process current memory and CPU consumption?

Sample code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_members.aspx) has a GetProcesses method that will let you enumerate the running processes and list a bunch of stats like memory usage and CPU time. Look at the documentation under properties for the stats.

Memory usage is a complex matter. There is really no single number, that describe the usage. Please see Russinovich's excellent series on the matter. The first installment is here: http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx

Comment: I know about the class, but I couldn't figure out how to get CPU consumption, or which of the 100 memory related fields actually means the real RAM consumption.

Comment: Memory usage is a bit complex, but my guess is you probably want to look at PrivateMemory.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by RAM (memory) consumption. Windows stores at least two values for the amount of memory being used by a process. The physical memory in use, and the size of the virtual memory allocated to the process. both are consumption...

Comment: The various ProcessorTime properties gives you kernel, user and sum for CPU usage. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I'm basically looking for the values that would be in the task manager as well.

Comment: @kdmurray: it is actually more complex than that. You also have memory mappings shared/private, reserved vs. commit and so forth.

Comment: Task manager has numerous options for memory usage similar to what the Process class gives you. As for CPU load % I believe there's a performance counter for that, but I am not sure. I'll have a look.

Comment: I tried experimenting with the performance counter but it doesn't seem to give an immediate read (it takes like a second to read - measurement time?) or i do something wrong, i dont know.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx for info on performance counters

Comment: I studied the page earlier today, and it seems way too complex for the task?

Comment: Well process monitor is a bit complex. If you want to give the user a simplified view of the world, you need to figure out how you want to simplify it.

Comment: @Alex To get a explanation of *why* the performance counter "has a delay" see [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462331/i-need-to-call-accurate-cpu-usage-of-a-single-process/8462977#8462977) of mine where I go in to a little depth of the *why*.