# Get Kernel Times in C#

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the Kenel time of an opertaion for eg: networking, disk I/O or other kernel tasks using a C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see: [Get current CPU, RAM and Disk drive usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253154/get-current-cpu-ram-and-disk-drive-usage-in-c)