# How do I get disk utilization info in C#

Tags: c#, windows-10, taskmanager

How can I go about getting disk utilization info in Windows 10 similar to the way Task Manager does?

I want to do these in order:

1. Log to console
2. Display in a widget or tray icon

End goal is to be able to throttle or shut down programs depending on average disk utilization over a specific period.

C# preferred C++ also acceptable

The accuracy is important, so if I need to use the same API as Task Manager   that can be done.

**note**

I do not mean disk space utilization but read-write utilization.

Comment: Look into performance counters -- they can give you all sorts of nice information in Windows, and are available in .NET pretty easily. https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-counters/

Comment: Did you see [Get current CPU, RAM and Disk drive usage in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253154/3744182)?

Comment: yes. that question refers to disk space used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in a timer_tick method:

```
    PerformanceCounter disk = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Time", "_Total");
    Int32 j = 0;
    j = Convert.ToInt32(disk.NextValue());
    Console.WriteLine(j);
```

The code is in C#

Comment: Although this answer may help the OP, but an explanation of your solution would be great for the OP and anyone else that may come across it.

Comment: Perhaps even a MSDN link to the documentation regarding the PerformanceCounter class. Google is no mind reader.