# APIs supported with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, capability

I want to develop a Windows 10 app (something similar to Windows Store app) .
I want to know , would I be able to get the following details from my app

1. CPU Usage and show top Metro apps consuming RAM
2. Getting list of all the apps installed.
3. Battery Usage , list apps consuming more battery
4. Kill apps consuming more RAM and CPU
5. Switch On /OFF wifi , Bluetooth from the app only

Any idea if these would be supported or not or shall I go with a WPF application

Comment: Your application would need administrative permissions - are you sure you want to create one? It's a risk for the client and for you, too, if it gets hacked. In any case the Metro style is done via WPF, it's not a choice.

Comment: yeah I want to create one !! I dont want to hack into the system but I want to know do we have access to Hardware APIs or not

Comment: Yes, you have access to. Not from Windows 10, but way before.

As for the resources, have you tried on StackOverflow before asking? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342023/how-to-measure-the-total-memory-consumption-of-the-current-process-programatical

Comment: Did u read ? I am asking for Windows Runtime Apps not desktop apps ! Windows Runtime apps execute in Sandboxing mode and dont have system APIs

Comment: "Ya I red".

"I want to develop a Windows 10 app (something similar to Windows Store app) . I want to know , would I be able to get the following details from my app" - where did you mention "windows runtime app"? In any case, if it's sandboxed, you can't access the other processes. It's the key of sandboxing.

Comment: Windows store apps are what ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the Windows Store app is not an app sold in the store itself. Please try to figure out your input may not be interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to gather this information from a Windows Store App (now called a "Windows Universal App"). Your best bet is to build a Desktop App (now called a "Classic Windows App") to get the information - and WPF is a fine choice if you already know how to use that.

Comment: What do you think ? What all can we achieve? would you please look into the above mentioned points. I need to access hardware programatically from my application.We want to go ahead with Windows universal App . Can we get the hardware functionality like switching On/Off from my app?

Comment: anyhow do you think there will be access to hardware when the Final version is released ! we want to target the Universal App concept but WPF  can be considered if it has answers to all our issues

Comment: The Universal Windows App Platform is primarily designed to build "apps" -- what you describe is more like a "system utility" that is best served by a Classic app. Over time, more functionality will be added to UWP (which might include some of these features) but right now you can't do this. Please use the Feedback app if you'd like to make a suggestion.

Comment: would you be able to provide me the link where I can ask for a feature to be added up ? Thanks

Comment: Windows Feedback Tool in Windows 10. There is a category for developer feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the features you list above (particularly "2.Getting list of all the apps installed." and "4.Kill apps consuming more RAM and CPU") require administrator rights. Windows 8 Store apps and universal Windows apps for Windows 10 run in a isolated security context called AppContainer that has *less* rights than a standard user much less an administrator. By design, these apps do not have the ability to impact other apps or system systems generally.

Answer (score 1):

At least for #5, there is [this new API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.aspx) in Windows 10.

I don't know of a solution for 1-4.

Comment: thanks for your reply ! I saw the Link but again Making the bluetooth auto discoverable and turn it on /off

Comment: what do you mean "auto discoverable"?