# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in itextsharp.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create pdf. I have 100k records, but I am getting following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in
>   itextsharp.dll but was not handled in user code At the line:
>   bodyTable.AddCell(currentProperty.GetValue(lst, null).ToString());

Code is:

```
var doc = new Document(pageSize);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
doc.Open();

//Get exportable count
int columns = 0;

Type currentType = list[0].GetType();

//PREPARE HEADER
//foreach visible columns check if current object has proerpty
//else search in inner properties
foreach (var visibleColumn in visibleColumns)
{
    if (currentType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key) != null)
    {
        columns++;
    }
    else
    {
        //check child property objects
        var childProperties = currentType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in childProperties)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key) != null)
                {
                    columns++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//header
var headerTable = new PdfPTable(columns);
headerTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;

foreach (var visibleColumn in visibleColumns)
{
    if (currentType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key) != null)
    {
        //headerTable.AddCell(prop.Name);
        headerTable.AddCell(visibleColumn.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        //check child property objects
        var childProperties = currentType.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in childProperties)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity))
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key) != null)
                {
                    //headerTable.AddCell(prop.Name);
                    headerTable.AddCell(visibleColumn.Value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

doc.Add(headerTable);

var bodyTable = new PdfPTable(columns);
bodyTable.Complete = false;
bodyTable.WidthPercentage = 100f;

//PREPARE DATA
foreach (var lst in list)
{
    int col = 1;
    foreach (var visibleColumn in visibleColumns)
    {
        var currentProperty = currentType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key);
        if (currentProperty != null)
        {
            if (currentProperty.GetValue(lst, null) != null)
                bodyTable.AddCell(currentProperty.GetValue(lst, null).ToString());
            else
                bodyTable.AddCell(string.Empty);

            col++;
        }
        else
        {
            //check child property objects
            var childProperties = currentType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity));
            foreach (var prop in childProperties)
            {
                currentProperty = prop.PropertyType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == visibleColumn.Key);
                if (currentProperty != null)
                {
                    var currentPropertyObjectValue = prop.GetValue(lst, null);
                    if (currentPropertyObjectValue != null)
                    {
                        bodyTable.AddCell(currentProperty.GetValue(currentPropertyObjectValue, null).ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bodyTable.AddCell(string.Empty);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

doc.Add(bodyTable);

doc.Close();
```

Comment: A stack trace would be useful. Also, what's the size of the data involved. One lakh == 10000 right? But how big is each record? How much memory does the system have in total? Perhaps it is a genuine case of the computer running out of memory.

Comment: one lakh = 100000. Means 100000 rows and 40 columns. Each cell containing approx 20 character data. My System is having 8 GB RAM.

Comment: What is a lakh? I have never heard that word before.

Answer (score 1):

A back of the envelope computation of the memory requirements given the data you provided for memory consumption gives 100000 * 40 * (2*20+4) = 167MBs. Well within your memory limit, but it is just a lower bound. I imagine each Cell object is pretty big. If each cell would have a 512 byte overhead you could be well looking at 2GB taken. I reckon it might be even more, as PDF is a complex beast.

So you might realistically be looking at a situation where you are actually running out of memory. If not your computers, then at least the bit C# has set aside for its own thing.

I would do one thing first - check memory consumption like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342023/how-to-measure-the-total-memory-consumption-of-the-current-process-programatical). You might even do well to try with 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 rows and see up until what number of rows the program works.

You could perhaps try a different thing altogether. If you're trying to print a nicely formatted table with a lot of data, perhaps you could output an HTML document, which can be done incrementally and which you can do by just writing stuff to a file, rather than using a third party library. You can then "print" that HTML document to PDF. StackOverflow to the [rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php) again with this problem.

Comment: It's not Java but .NET, so you may want to modify your answer.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse oops, that's a funny mistake to make. Thanks for pointing it out. I changed the suggestions to C#. Like before, it's not a solution, but rather some avenues for investigation which might help Sachin.